# canvas rename? - stay on the page

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am not able to turn that *toDataURL* a link, type */img.png*

```
data:image/gif;base64,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
```

so, it only changes when you download

```
<a href="MY_CANVAS_URL" download="img">Download</a>
```

I need this image renamed

stay on the page

---

Solution?

Answer (score 1):

[ Edited: ]

**Here's how to generate a link that uses the download attribute to load a canvas dataURL**

```
// take in a filename and dataURL
// return a new anchor element with download attribute
function newDownloadAnchor(filename,dataURL) {
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.download = filename;
    anchor.title = "Get the canvas";
    anchor.href = dataURL;
    return(anchor);
}


// get a referenct to the canvas
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");

// capture the canvas as a URL
var theURL=canvas.toDataURL();

// create a new anchor with download attribute
var newAnchor=newDownloadAnchor("myFile.png",theURL);

// append the new anchor to the DOM
var parent=document.getElementById("appendToThisId");
parent.appendChild(newAnchor);
```

*You can use canvas to convert a Gif to PNG on the client-side*

```
// create a temporary canvas
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// make the canvas the same size as the image
canvas.width=image.width;
canvas.height=image.height;

// draw the gif on the canvas
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);

// save the canvas toDataURL – the default format is PNG
var pngDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/gZ87t/

This code converts the gif to a png and displays it in an img-tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var gifDataURL="data:image/gif;base64,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";

    convertGifToPng(gifDataURL,callback);

    function convertGifToPng(gifURL,callback){

        var image=new Image();
        image.onload=function(){

            var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width=image.width;
            canvas.height=image.height;
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
            var pngDataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            callback(pngDataURL);
        }
        image.src=gifDataURL;

    }

    function callback(pngURL){
        document.getElementById("theImage").src=pngURL;
        console.log(pngURL);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <img id="theImage"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this NOT, replace `data:image/gif;base64,` to `image.png`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you need.  Do you want to use the download attribute to get a dataURL/